# Drupal 7 views join two profile2 profiles together

Tags: views, users

I would like to join two profile2 profiles so they appear as one row in the view module and not two rows like the example below. Can this be done?

[image: screenshot]

#### Fields

- User: Name
- Content: image_profile_image

#### Relationships

- User: Profile
- User: Content authored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Display Suit](http://drupal.org/project/ds).

Also [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) is a good solution for this.

Oskar

Comment: Hi Oskar I updated my question. Does that help better to explain what i require. As you can see the image shows two images both with name but only one profile2 profile is displayed.

Comment: In this case maybe use a views, with /%uid, and choose what elements must bee show with the views fields tpls. It's harder but it works also.